# How to capture the value from a drop down list created using <ul> <li> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a drop down list having country names with their flag images. Since we cannot create such a list using `<select> <option>` tags, I created it using `<ul> <li>`. Now I want to capture the value selected by user and use it for some other purpose. How can I do it?

This is how the list has been created:

```
<form id="formId" action="" method="post" class="loginForm">
  <fieldset id="localeSelect">
   <div>
     <div  id="localeIndicator">
      <a href="#" title="Select a country">
       <span class="united-kingdom"></span>UK &ndash; English
      </a>
    </div>
    <ul class="no-bullets block-list" role="tablist">
     <li><a href="#"><span class="austria"></span>Austria</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
 <input type="hidden" name="locale" />
 <input type="submit" value="Continue" />
</fieldset>
```

Comment: can you please post a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this.Have a look at fiddle

Fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/rmsg7/)

It will give you an idea.

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    alert("The selected Value is "+ $("ul").find(".selected").data("value"));
});
```

Comment: Such a great example.
Please, note @Richa is using jQuery, don't forget to add this library

Comment: @user3641092 Good to know it helped you 
:)

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit hacky solution but using data-* attribute to give each item a unique value (not always the best option, but certainly one of the most commonly used if you ask me).

```
<div id="my-div">
    <ul>
        <li data-src="info to get here">something</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And with jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#my-div li").click(function() {
        var data = $(this).attr("data-src");
    });
});
```

You can style the li to be: cursor: pointer; to have a finger when you hover it.

```
selector li:hover { cursor: pointer; }
```

[Here's a fiddle to show it](http://jsfiddle.net/pjB4T/1/)